# About modal operators in Blender Python

Tags: python, blender

I want to make a program that uses modal operators to continue printing ("test") every 0.01 seconds in Blender's Python.

I also want to exit when I press the Esc key.

What can I do?

I wrote and executed the following code, but Blender freezes. Using a modal operator seems to be able to avoid freezing, but I wasn't sure how to use it.

```
import time
import threading

#A function that keeps executing print ("test")
def worker():
    while True:
        print("test")

def schedule(interval, f, wait=True):
    base_time = time.time()
    next_time = 0
    while True:
        t = threading.Thread(target=f)
        t.start()
        if wait:
            t.join()
        next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
        time.sleep(next_time)

#Execute worker function every 0.01 second
schedule(0.01, worker, False)
```

Comment: Please try to write the code yourself first, then if you are still having trouble, post your code and we can try and help you.

Comment: The [`subprocess` module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45747/935) works better while [`threading` has issues](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-using-threading-module). You may also be interested in [this modal example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71830/935), note that it uses `"INVOKE_DEFAULT"` to start the rendering operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In blenders text editor you will find a python template called [`operator_modal_timer.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_modal_timer.py) that works the way you want.

The first call to the operator is the `execute()` method, where you create the timer with [`wm.event_timer_add`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.event_timer_add). Then in the `modal()` method you respond to the timer events or cancel the operator if you get an `esc` key event.

If you put the operator in [an addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html), you can have it enabled every time you start blender.